# Finding value within Dict Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a `Dict` called `json_response`.
I am trying to loop over each element in the `Dict`, and if `x['name'] = "LOCATION"` assign variable Lat and Long the value of `x['geometry']['location']['lat']` and append to list

```
for x in json_response['results']:
    if "LOCATION" in x['name'].lower():
        Lat = x['geometry']['location']['lat'] 
        Long = x['geometry']['location']['lng']
        ATMLat.append(Lat)
        ATMLong.append(Long)
```

However, If there are 2 other elements that are in the list which do not equal LOCATION, then ignore (we have already appended `Lat`&`Long` to list). If there are NO elements which equal LOCATION then append "No Match" to list

Right now my code appends the `Lat` and `Long` to the list where Location in `x['name']` but need to add that if it isn't in the dict list then append a "no match" for the entire element, not per element

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `if "LOCATION" in x['name'].lower()` will never return True. You should use `if "LOCATION" == x['name'].upper()` or `if "LOCATION" in x['name'].upper()`.

Secondly, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you need to extract only one location per response, you can add `break`.

```
for x in json_response['results']:
    if "LOCATION" in x['name'].upper():
        Lat = x['geometry']['location']['lat'] 
        Long = x['geometry']['location']['lng']
        ATMLat.append(Lat)
        ATMLong.append(Long)
        break        # location found

ATMLat = ATMLat or ['No Match']
ATMLong = ATMLong or ['No Match']
```